# MongoDB: How do I return/access only one document from $elemMatch

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Say I have a students object array field e.g. `[{id:foo, name: bar, imageurl:baz}]`  in a courses collection. and I want to return *only* the courses that have a given student id in the students field.

If I use `$elemMatch`, I'll get a bunch of documents in the courses collection as well as the course i want. Is there a way around this or do I absolutely have to do some post query filtering to return only one doc?

EDIT: 
example courses collection:

```
{
 _id: 1,
 course: "OOP 101",
 students: [
              { name: "ajax", school: 100, age: 7 },
              { name: "achilles", school: 100, age: 8 },
           ]
}
{
 _id: 2,
 course: "Programming 101",
 students: [
              { name: "john", school: 102, age: 10 },
              { name: "ajax", school: 100, age: 7 },
              { name: "achilles", school: 100, age: 8 },
           ]
}
{
 _id: 3,
 course: "Database 101",
 students: [
              { name: "john", school: 102, age: 10 },
              { name: "jess", school: 102, age: 11 },
              { name: "jeff", school: 108, age: 15 }
           ]
}
```

Expected output if i use `$elemMatch` to find courses jeff is taking:

```
{
 _id: 3,
 course: "Database 101",
 students: [
              { name: "john", school: 102, age: 10 },
              { name: "jess", school: 102, age: 11 },
              { name: "jeff", school: 108, age: 15 }
           ]
}
```

versus

```
{
 _id: 1,
 course: "OOP 101"
{
 _id: 2,
 course: "Programming 101"
} 
{
 _id: 3,
 course: "Database 101",
 students: [
              { name: "john", school: 102, age: 10 },
              { name: "jess", school: 102, age: 11 },
              { name: "jeff", school: 108, age: 15 }
           ]
}
```

Comment: Can you at least show us some sample documents and the expected output?

Comment: I've edited your question to show a sample collection based on one link you gave. Could you **show an example** of the expected output ?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux Thanks for the help. I've edited the question to show the expected output!

Answer (score 2):

> I want to return only the courses that have a given student id in the students field

You can use [`$elemMatch` **in a query**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch) to select documents based on the value of a field in an embedded document. Then using a simple projection, you can get back *only* the fields of interest:

```
> db.test.courses.find(
     {students: {$elemMatch : { name: "john"}}},  // find all courses having 
                                                  // "john" as a student
     {course:1})                                  // keep only the course name
                                                  // and the _id
{ "_id" : 2, "course" : "Programming 101" }
{ "_id" : 3, "course" : "Database 101" }
```

---

Of course, if you need the whole document, do not specify any projection:

```
> db.test.courses.find(      {students: {$elemMatch : { name: "jeff"}}}).pretty()
{
    "_id" : 3,
    "course" : "Database 101",
    "students" : [
        {
            "name" : "john",
            "school" : 102,
            "age" : 10
        },
        {
            "name" : "jess",
            "school" : 102,
            "age" : 11
        },
        {
            "name" : "jeff",
            "school" : 108,
            "age" : 15
        }
    ]
}
```

Please notice this will return *all* courses having a student with a matching name. In our sample data, *"jeff"* is associated with only one course. But this would return two documents for *"john"*.

If you only want one of them, you might use the aggregation framework together with the `$limit` stage (for most cases, you *should* use a `$sort` stage before `$limit`) :

```
> db.test.courses.aggregate([
        {$match:{students: {$elemMatch : { name: "john"}}}},
        {$limit:1}
  ]).pretty()
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "course" : "Programming 101",
    "students" : [
        {
            "name" : "john",
            "school" : 102,
            "age" : 10
        },
        {
            "name" : "ajax",
            "school" : 100,
            "age" : 7
        },
        {
            "name" : "achilles",
            "school" : 100,
            "age" : 8
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hi i've edited the question to be more specific. The mongodb docs appear to show a response containing irrelevant courses (where the students field doesnt match it returns the course but hides the students field). Am i wrong about this?

Comment: @wemadeit Thank you for having clarified your needs. AFAIKT, using `$elemMatch` as I explained it should produce what you were expecting. I've edited to provide more details. Tested with MongoDB 3.0.2.

Comment: This isn't what the mongodb docs say will happen. check out the zipcode search example: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/ where { "_id" : 3 } is returned as a result even though it is not a match

Comment: @wemadeit `$elemMatch` could be used in two different contexts. As a [projection operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) (this is the use case described in the doc you linked) and as a [query operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch) (this is what I used here). Please take some time to compare both docs and to experiment with that. I assure you that I ran those commands before posting the answer, and *it works*... as described for the **query operator**.